# Disable default Swagger jaxrs2 openapi url

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs

we are documenting our JAX-RS API with swagger. By using the `swagger-jaxrs2` package, we can create an build our api documentation very well.

The only thing we want to change: the default "openapi"-Url. 
By registering Swaggers OpenApiResource Class, our application produces everytime the default `"[host]/openapi"` Endpoint.

We are able to create our own endpoint which serves the openapi-spec, but we cannot disable this default endpoint.

Every hint is welcome! Tank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved with a workaround: Modifing `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` to load just the Endpoints which we provide by our own, ignoring any other 3rdParty endpoint like the swagger-jaxrs2 `openapi` or `openapi.{type:json|yaml}`

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class OurApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // Start detecting only classes in your package! provided 3rdParty packages 
        // (like io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources) won't be provided
        Reflections ourClasses = new Reflections("our.package.naming");

        // Scan your classed for @javax.ws.rs.Path Annotaion. We need just collect 
        // API-Endpoints
        Set<Class<?>> ourEndpoints = ourClasses.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class); 

        // fyi - log the registered classes / endpoints
        System.out.println("Providing "+ ourEndpoints);       

        // return endpoints to provide it in your application
        return ourEndpoints; 
    }

}
```

HINT: Due to @ApplicationPath annotation there is no need to modify web.xml.

The Reflections we used are provided by maven:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
      <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Watch https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections for more information about the reflections package.

We didn't find a better solution but this is what worked for us. Enjoy it.

Comment: Very helpful solution although at the end I ended up using the javax-rs library included in the javaee-api and had no problem exposing mine openapi or openapi.{type:json|yaml} .